# Weekly email newsletter in laravel 4

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to send auto generated weekly newsletter from my laravel project. From a controller I want to send some result of the laravel query in a newslater form to all the user in the list.

At this moment I can send the mail to single user when they are knocking some operation themselves . Now I want a auto generation of email on a particular frequent of time (day/ week /month )  ... also I want to send those mail to all the user in the db, in a loop. thank you for helping me in this tiny research :)

Comment: Should probably go with a cronjob.

Comment: thank you for your kind reply sir, At first I will go for Antonio's solution, if it goes wrong, I will need your help.As the cronjob seems to be lill more complicated. :)

Comment: His reply is already using cronjobs. It's the last part of it.

Comment: ok, Friend, Can you please provide me some readable content on web to know this cronjob better ? Compact read will be awesome. Thanks btw.

Comment: Since I don't know it myself, I have no good reference to point you to, I'm sorry.

Comment: Its ok Sir ! Thank you for your kind reply :) [my site](http://dolovers.com/)

Answer (score 9):

**Create an [artisan command](http://laravel.com/docs/commands):**

```
php artisan command:make SendNewletterCommand
```

In app/commands, edit the SendNewletterCommand.php and:

Set your command name:

```
protected $name = 'newsletter:send';
```

Create your fire() method:

```
public function fire()
{
   foreach(User::all() as $user)
   {
        Mail::send('emails.newletter', $data, function($message) use ($user)
        {
            $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Welcome!');
        });
   }
}
```

Register your command in artisan by editing app/start/artisan.php and adding:

```
Artisan::add(new SendNewletterCommand);
```

And add your new command to your crontab:

```
0 0 * * sun php /your/project/path/artisan newsletter:send
```

It will send your e-mails every sunday at midnight.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply sir. I will try all this and when it is done I ll mark this as answered. In the mean time I may need you help to proceed. Thank you thank you :)

Comment: Sir I am very much new at the cronjob . Can you please provide me some read about it ?

Comment: It's very easy to use it. Basically you run `sudo crontab -e` to edit root`s crontab and add your jobs, one per line. Here is some good info about it: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/.

Comment: Sir, Do i need to have any new package for cornjob or I should set the trigger from c-panel ? I am using laravel, is there the cornjob installed ? or the whole thing only can be started using hosting panel ?

Comment: If your server is Linux based, you have cron installed already. I'm 99.9% sure. Cron is a Linux/Unix service, no strings attached to PHP or Laravel, it's a system service to execute timed tasks.

Comment: yes I my server is linux based. But I never run a command like `sudo crontab ....` before and do not know where from it should be executed ... can we have any manual alternatives command or path ...

Comment: cPanel can help you with it: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs.

Comment: Sir what is the best place to write fire method in ?

Comment: Sir I am not sure about the path of the project can you help me with that ?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: in the control panel or cpanel what wuld be the command line for the path ... 

my structure is like ,
one dolovers forlder which is having all the dev file and public_html for all the public of laravel , now what would be the command for the cronjob call ?

Comment: If you don't have SSH access to your server, you'll need to ask your server support/administrators to tell you the exact path of your application. In this case I'm pretty sure you cannot use a relative path or something like that.

Comment: I have ssl facility But I am very new to use it ... can you pls tell me how the link structure should be maintain ?

Comment: SSL != SSH. SSH is terminal access to your server. You really have to know where your files are in the hard drive of your server.

Comment: actually I am getting a mail in the seding mail id , which is , 

/bin/sh: /home/dolovers/artisan: No such file or directory

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43190/discussion-between-antonio-carlos-ribeiro-and-sagiruddin-mondal)

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro can you check out my question about sending a newsletter every month with mandrill in laravel 5.1, would appreciate any help :)

Comment: when you mention the instruction "php artisan command:make SendNewletterCommand" it should be "make:command" instead of "command:make"